Finding $x$ such that $x$, $x+2$, and $x+4$ are the sides of a right triangle
Trying to solve all the sides of this triangle, using Pythagorean Theorem.

Attempt:
$x^2 + (x+2)^2 = (x+4)^2$
$x^2 + (x+2)(x+2) = (x+4)(x+4)$
$x^2 + (x^2 + 4x + 4) = x^2 + 8x + 8$
$x^2 - 4x - 4 = 0$
$x = 2 \pm \sqrt{2^2 - 4}$
$x = 2 \pm \sqrt{0}$
$x = 2$
In my book, the correct answer is $x = 6$.

$4^2=16$ not $8$.

@lulu, where do you mean?

$(x+4)^2=x^2+(2\times 4)x+4^2$.

The triangle $(x,x+2,x+4)=(6,8,10)$ is congruent to $(3,4,5)$, which is just $3^2+4^2=5^2$. The multiples of $(3,4,5)$ are the only Pythagorean triples, which form an arithmetic progression. Hence $x$ must be a multiple of $3$.

$x^2+(x+2)^2=(x+4)^2$
$x^2+(x+2)(x+2)=(x+4)(x+4)$
$x^2+(x^2+4x+4)=x^2+8x+16$
$x^2-4x-12=0$
$x=2\pm\sqrt{2^2+12}$
$x=2\pm\sqrt{16}$
$x=2\pm4$
So there are two solutions:
$x=-2\;\lor\;x=6$
but the solution $\,x=-2\,$ cannot be accepted because it is negative and the length of a side is always positive, so the only solution to your problem is $\,x=6\,$.
Indeed in your book, the correct answer is $\,x=6\,$.

Thanks. How did you go from: $x^2 - 4x - 12= 0$ to $x = 2 \pm \sqrt{2^2+12}$ ? I got it, to -12, but, you wrote positive 12.

The formula for the quadratic equation $;ax^2+bx+c=0;$ is $$x=\dfrac{-\frac b2\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac b2\right)^2-ac}}a$$ Since $ac=-12$, it follows that $-ac=12$.

Angelo, I am a bit confused. You know any links or videos that explain this in more basic easy to understand details?

Why is $- ac = 12$ ?

@AlixBlaine, in you equation, $a=1$ and $c=-12$, hence $ac=-12$ and $-ac=12$.

Your mistake is on the third line. It is supposed to be $x^2+8x+16$

So, it is supposed to be: $x^2 - 4x -12 = 0$ ?

Exactly. solve the roots according to this to obtain the results in your book.

... and what about the other root $x=-2$? :-) :-) :-)

The length of a side of a triangle must be a positive value.

As lulu pointed out in the comments, you squared $4$ incorrectly when expanding $(x + 4)^2$ using the formula $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ with $a = x$ and $b = 2$, which yields $(x + 4)^2 = x^2 + 2 \cdot 4x + 4^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16$.  In the calculation below, I chose to expand the products using the distributive law.  Notice that
\begin{align*}
(a + b)^2 & = (a + b)(a + b)\\
          & = a(a + b) + b(a + b)\\
          & = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2\\
          & = a^2 + ab + ab + b^2\\
          & = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{align*}
By the Pythagorean Theorem,
\begin{align*}
x^2 + (x + 2)^2 & = (x + 4)^2\\
x^2 + (x + 2)(x + 2) & = (x + 4)(x + 4)\\
x^2 + x(x + 2) + 2(x + 2) & = x(x + 4) + 4(x + 4)\\
x^2 + x^2 + 2x + 2x + 4 & = x^2 + 4x + 4x + 16\\
2x^2 + 4x + 4 & = x^2 + 8x + 16\\
x^2 - 4x - 12 & = 0\\
x^2 - 6x + 2x - 12 & = 0\\
x(x - 6) + 2(x - 6) & = 0\\
(x + 2)(x - 6) & = 0
\end{align*}
Since a product is equal to zero if and only if one of its factors is equal to zero,
\begin{align*}
x + 2 & = 0 & \text{or} & & x - 6 & = 0\\
x & = -2 & & & x & = 6
\end{align*}
Since a side length cannot be negative, the solution $x = -2$ is extraneous.  Therefore, $x = 6$.  Hence, $x + 2 = 8$ and $x + 4 = 10$.

An option:
$x^2+(x+2)^2=[(x+2)+2]^2;$
$x^2+(x+2)^2=$
$(x+2)^2+2\cdot2 (x+2)+2^2;$
$x^2-4(x+2)-4=0;$
$x^2-4x-12=0;$
$(x-6)(x+2)=0 $
and we are done.

In general, if $a = x$, $b = x + r$, $c = x + 2r$, we have an arithmetic progression. Then
$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ is equivalent to
$$
(x + r)(x - 3r) = 0
$$
If $x = -r$, then $b = 0$, which we exclude. Hence $x = 3r$, which gives:
$$
a = 3r,\ b = 4r,\ c = 5r
$$
Therefore, $(3, 4, 5)$ and its multiples are the only arithmetic progressions which are also a Pythagorean triple. In our case, $r=2$, so our triple $(x,x+2,x+4)$ is $(6,8,10)$.
